# Method signature based on previous method call

Tags: typescript

I need to program a value transformation based on various steps. In order to reuse the steps, an architecture was proposed where the steps can be passed to the transformation, similar to this code (e.g. to uppercase a long string and truncate it after 13 characters):

```
Transformation.from("This is a long story").step(Uppercase).step(Truncate);

class Uppercase {
  public run(str: string): string {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }
}

class Truncate {
  public run(str: string): string {
    return str.substr(0, 10) + '...';
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make sure (preferrably at compile time) that the steps are compatible with each other, i.e. that the output of one step is type-compatible with the input of the next, so the following class isn't allowed after a step producing a string:

```
class SquareRoot {
  public run(num: number): number {
    return Math.sqrt(num);
  }
}
```

Achieving this at runtime seems possible by adding the two members `inputType` and `outputType` to the steps and comparing them, but I'd like to do the check at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define the `Transformer` class.

```
class Transformation<T> {
  constructor(readonly value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static from<U>(input: U): Transformation<U> {
    return new Transformation(input);
  }

  public step<U>(transformer: Transformer<T, U>): Transformation<U> {
    return new Transformation(transformer.run(this.value));
  }
}
```

It uses a `Transformer` interface. We can define it as:

```
interface Transformer<T, U> {
  run(input: T): U;
}
```

With that in place, the transformations are guaranteed to be correct in compile-time.

```
Transformation.from("This is a long story")
  .step(new Uppercase())
  .step(new Truncate()); // OK

Transformation.from("This is a long story")
  .step(new Uppercase())
  .step(new SquareRoot()); // Compile-time error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

**Update**

Note: in your example, you're passing *constructors* of `Uppercase` and `Truncate` as your `step`s. In my solution, *instances* are used instead. If you insist on passing constructors instead, you will need to make the `run` method static.

```
class Uppercase {
  public static run(str: string): string {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }
}

class Truncate {
  public static run(str: string): string {
    return str.substr(0, 10) + '...';
  }
}

class SquareRoot {
  public static run(num: number): number {
    return Math.sqrt(num);
  }
}

Transformation.from("This is a long story")
  .step(Uppercase)
  .step(Truncate);

Transformation.from("This is a long story")
  .step(Uppercase)
  .step(SquareRoot); // Compile-time error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I solved it in a quite similiar way. You can see it on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p47mmn
There you can see it's not necessary to create static methods for the step classes. It's also possible to use `step(transformer: { new(): T})` and instantiate it within the function.

Comment: Wow.That's beautiful. Instances work fine btw. The constructors are a relict of an earlier try but by no means a requirement.